# How do I split data in a textbox into multiple lines after getting info from downloadstring?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've made a program that gets proxys from an api by downloadstring into a textbox, however its not formatted properly, and doesnt split into seperate lines. This is what I mean.

[image]

And this is my code.

[image]

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question and put the code as text/code.

Comment: Is this `WPF` or `WinForms`?

Comment: @Stefan winforms

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
var text = input.Replace("<br/>", Environment.NewLine);
```

And assign it to the TextBox text.

Comment: You beat me to it ;-)

Comment: this didnt work :/

Comment: try this,  var text = input.Replace("<br>", "/r/n").Replace("<br/>", "/r/n").Replace("<br />", "/r/n");